# Start air/flex application with windows

Tags: windows, apache-flex, air

I want to provides an option in my air/flex application. A user can check an option and the application starts when windows starts.

I don't find with google how to do this, someone knows do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot start a flex app when Windows boots; but u can launch an AIR app when the user logs in (not when windows boots up). It can be done with:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.startAtLogin = true;
```

[Check this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a5d46-8000.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7cd5) for details